# Bitcoin, MinGW, Windows 7, Makefile error

Tags: c++, windows, qt, makefile, bitcoin

I am currently creating 'Bitcoin' on my windows 7.

I have done all the necessary steps and I am now left for the last part, to get the .exe file.

This is the command i typed in to my QT 4.8.5 command prompt

```
qmake USE_UPNP=- "C:\barcoin-master\barcoin-qt.pro"
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
```

And what happens next is a very very long list on the command prompt and the error i get at the end says

```
Makefile.Release:1032 recipe for target 'build/irc.o' failed
mingw32-make: ***[build/irc.o] Error 1
```

Can anybody help? I read some forums that says I have to uncomment line 91-94 on C:\MinGW\include\windows.h to solve this error, which I did, but to no avail.

Please advise! Thanks

This is the link to my barcoin-qt.pro file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bz7m8w7fyd740yv/barcoin-qt.pro

Comment: Can you show your pro file?

Comment: Hi I have updated the link on my post

Comment: That is a _very_ complex pro file. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Don't upload sourcecode to dropbox. Use pastebin instead. I'm not going to download a random file from a random person on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

it's now working for me now! It is a problem from the compiler itself (MinGW). You need to download an old version http://www57.zippyshare.com/v/72961800/file.html
And then select gcc, g++ and msys base. Normally, if you do make -f Makefile.Release again , it's working. I suggest you to clean what you made before and recompile everything again.